'No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page' while retrieving a specific image from a database
I'm trying to retrieve an image from a PostGreSQL library and place it into a TImage component.
To store the image, I'm using a bytearray column named 'user_profile_pic'.
I get my image from a TImage component (for uploading it to the database).
For displaying the image after retrieving it from the database, I use another TImage component.
To communicate with my database, I use the PgDac library.
While I'm retrieving images from the database, there is a specific image that causes the following error:

Project MyProject.exe raised exception class EEncodingError with message 'No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page'.

The image that causes the crash is this image of David Bowie. I have linked the image instead of uploading it here, because I don't know if StackOverflow changes anything to an image that could possibly fix it).
Every other image that I've tried works. It is just this image that causes the error.
I have found other StackOverflow answers with this error, but most of them are about other types of files that support UTF-8 encoding, not images.
The code to upload an image to the database is:
procedure TfrmMyForm.btnUploadImageClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  AStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  //fileExtension gets used while uploading the image to a TImage.
  pgqUploadProfilePicture.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO users_tbl (user_profile_extension, user_profile_pic)';
  pgqUploadProfilePicture.SQL.Add('VALUES (:ProfilePictureExtension, :ProfilePicture)');
  pgqUploadProfilePicture.ParamByName('ProfilePictureExtension').AsString := fileExtension; 
  //saves the image to a format that is used by the database
  AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    imgProfilePicture.Picture.SaveToStream(AStream);
    pgqUploadProfilePicture.ParamByName('ProfilePicture').LoadFromStream(AStream, ftBlob);
    pgqUploadProfilePicture.Execute;    

  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;
end;

And the code to retrieve the image is:
//user gets retrieved in another method
procedure TfrmGetImage.btnGetImageFromDB(Sender: TObject);
var
  stream: TStream;
begin
  //get image from retrieved user
  stream := pgqCheckExistingUser.CreateBlobStream(pgqCheckExistingUser.FieldByName('user_profile_pic'), bmRead);
  stream.Position := 0;
  imgGetImgFromDB.Picture.LoadFromStream(stream);
end;

The error happens in this statement:
imgGetImgFromDB.Picture.LoadFromStream(stream)

Does anyone know how I could fix this?
EDIT:
I was wrong about the CreateBlobStream() part, it should've been the LoadFromStream() part. I've highlighted where the error occurs.
An example of an image that works would be this image of the Delphi logo.

Shouldn't you are loading user_profile_pic, instead of user_profile_extension ?

I used placeholders for the database names in the question (but not in the code itself), but thanks for noticing, I will try to change my question.

An Insert SQL statement is called with .ExecSQL, not with .Open!

Yes, you're right. I fixed it in the question, thank you for pointing it out.

Why are you using TMemoryStream in btnUploadImageClick and TStream in btnGetImageFromDB? Why not use TMemoryStream in both methods?

Check if you .pas is saved in UTF8 econcoding. Look at the very bottom line of the editor, you'll find a combo box with char encoding setting

If the error truly happens within CreateBlobStream then you should trace into it and see what it does.
But from the error message, my thought is that the routine is written in pre-UNICODE time and uses STRINGs to store binary data. This is a no-no (and has been forever, but ANSI is far more forgiving than UNICODE for this).
If my suspicion is correct, you'll have to update the routine to use a TBytes (TArray<BYTE>) to store the data instead of a STRING (which is what it should have done in the first place).
Unfortunately, as we can't see the exact line where the error occurs, we are limited to guessing, but this error only occurs when trying to convert binary data into a STRING, so it is a very likely scenario.

This could be right, since both filename and metadata in the picture have valid UTF-8 - then it should be offset $355 with $c0. However, a bad UTF-8 sequence should happen with more binary files/pictures, not just the one in question. @PlastikLight please upload a working picture, too.

@AmigoJack, thank you for looking at my question. I have updated my question with an image that works

PNG would right away start with a bad UTF-8 sequence, so it's not the entirety of the file either. No, you have to debug more and pinpoint if it really comes from .LoadFromStream() and not PgDac itself. Why not asking them for support (rhetorical question)?
